# Placeholder label - labeling without object

Tags: cross-referencing

For a poster and a presentation, due to the small size of a document I want to avoid writing the information about the publications in a cumbersome bibtex file, but rather cite everything directly in the document. For example in the end I want to create manual bibliography:

- `papername1 label1 description1` (only papername and description are depicted in the document)
- `papername2 label2 description2`...

Then in the text I want to reference the labels by name, which can be done by for example `\nameref{label1}` and `papername1` should be shown .

For now I resort to just typing it without a label and referencing by just writing the `papername` manually.

Would be cool to know if it works with a label without looking at BibTeX file. Would be nice to know some solution without a BibTeX (or at least only automatically generated BibTeX file without a lot of typing) and without the need to write in the variables in the BibTeX convention for a certain type of paper (for example article, book, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use some predefined interface like presented below - `\paperdesc{<paper>}{<description>}` to set your paper descriptions, you can use it to automatically update `\@currentlabel` (the macro that holds the current label value). Updating it to `<paper>` allows you to use `\label`-`\ref` as per usual, retrieving the appropriate `<paper>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\paperdesc}[2]{%
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname % If using hyperref
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}% Update the current label
  \textsc{#1}, % Print paper in Small Caps
  #2% Print paper description
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See~\ref{paper:first} and~\ref{paper:third}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \paperdesc{Paper 1}{Description of Paper 1} \label{paper:first}
  \item \paperdesc{Paper B}{Description of Paper B}
  \item \paperdesc{Paper III}{Description of Paper III} \label{paper:third}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This solution may require more work if used in conjunction with other non-standard document classes or packages.